# Specific Time Zone In boost::posix_time::ptime

Tags: c++, boost

I have the following time :

```
2010-01-25 03:13:34.384 - GMT Time Zone
2010-01-25 11:13:34.384 - My Local
```

I wish to convert to timestamp in ms. However, since I only obtain local time string from caller
"2010-01-25 11:13:34.384"

If I do it this way :

```
// ts is "2010-01-25 11:13:34.384" (My Local)
boost::posix_time::ptime t(boost::posix_time::time_from_string(ts));
boost::posix_time::ptime end(boost::gregorian::date(1970,1,1));
boost::posix_time::time_duration dur = t - end;
// epoch is 1264418014384
// 2010-01-25 11:13:34.384 (GMT)  -- But I want 2010-01-25 03:13:34.384
// 2010-01-25 19:13:34.384 (My Local) -- But I want 2010-01-25 11:13:34.384
long long epoch = dur.total_milliseconds();
```

Is there any way to tell boost::posix_time, that the ts string which it receives, is belong to My Local timezone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have this in my local tree (namespace prefix omitted):

```
    /// wall-clock translation to UTC
    const ptime from_wall_clock( const ptime& value,
                                 const time_zone_ptr& from )
    {
        assert( from.get());

        // interpret as local time
        const local_date_time from_local( value.date(),
            value.time_of_day(), from,
            local_date_time::NOT_DATE_TIME_ON_ERROR );

        // get UTC
        return from_local.utc_time();
    }
```

Comment: May I know how do you obtain current time zone?

Comment: You keep it in TZ environment variable.

Answer (score 2):

I think you should be using `boost::local_date_time`, which handles time zones. There is an example in the documentation that is very similar to what you're trying to do: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/doc/html/date_time/examples.html#date_time.examples.seconds_since_epoch